# Remove HTML elements containing no characters or &nbsp;

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I'm working with some generated `HTML`, from a Word document, where I would like to extract *only* paragraph elements containing fully capitalized characters, *and* that do not contain only "empty elements" or `&nbsp;`. I'm currently using `javascript` / `jquery` and `regex` to determine what `<p class="foo">` elements to extract - please see the snippet:

```js
var allCaps = /^(?=.{1})(\s*[A-Z,\s]+\s*$)/,
    whitespace = /^|s+$/, 
    cont = $('<div class="container">'),
    elems = $('p[class^="foo"]');

elems.each(function(){
  var txt = $(this).first().text();
  if(allCaps.test(txt)){
    if(whitespace.test(txt)){
      var copy = cont.clone();
      var cln = $(this).clone();
      copy.append(cln);
      $('body').append(copy);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.container{
  padding: 5px;
  border: solid 2px steelblue;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="foo">I INTRODUCTION</p>
<p class="foo"><span></span></p>
<!-- THIS ELEMENT IS BEING COPIED -->
<p class="foo">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
```

You'll notice that the third `foo` paragraph is included in the `allCaps` and `whitespace` tests because of the `&nbsp;`. Is there any way I can exclude it? In other words, is there a regex, or other method, that can be used to capture just the first `foo` in the snippet example?

Comment: You might find [HTML Tidy](https://infohound.net/tidy/) useful if you have to work with Word generated HTML a lot. (Among other things it removes empty paragraphs). I'm not affiliated with this project but I used it a lot years ago when I had to edit content provided by clients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jquery `.text()` function already decodes your html entities, so you don't have to worry about it.

The problem here is with your regex `\s*[A-Z,\s]+\s*`, which matches a string with just spaces.

Try something like this instead

```
/^\s*[A-Z][A-Z,\s]*$/
```

Comment: This works well - only it's also grabbing `<p>` elements that contain lower case characters. I'm new to regex, this is how I've transposed what you posted: `/^\s*[A-Z]+[A-Z,\s]*/`